# Show SQL Server Group by Data into a Chart

Tags: html, chart.js

I'm working on a chart project. It could be Chartjs.org or Google Chart.

I can retrieve data from SQL Server and show it in a gridview. My question is that how can I show that data directly in a bar chart. And the data retrieved from SQL Server is grouped by a condition. If it's possible using an API, then please give me some code.

Comment: Hello, can you share some of the code that you are using to show the data in a grid view? This is in HTML correct?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a DataTable add below code to you c# and assign it to

```
<div class="card-body">                           
<asp:Literal ID="ltScripts" runat="server"></asp:Literal>  
<div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 465px; height: 400px;">            
</div>
```

C# Code:

```
DataTable dsChartData = new DataTable();
            StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
            try
            {
                dsChartData = GetChartData();
                strScript.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>  
                    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']}); </script>  
                      
                    <script type='text/javascript'>  
                     
                    function drawChart() {         
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  
                    ['Priority', 'Total'],");

                foreach (DataRow row in dsChartData.Rows)
                {
                    strScript.Append("['" + row["Priority"] + "'," + row["Total"] + "],");
                }
                strScript.Remove(strScript.Length - 1, 1);
                strScript.Append("]);");

                strScript.Append(@" var options = {     
                                           
                                    is3D: true,          
                                    };   ");

                strScript.Append(@"var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));          
                                chart.draw(data, options);        
                                }    
                            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);  
                            ");
                strScript.Append(" </script>");
                ltScripts.Text = strScript.ToString();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                dsChartData.Dispose();
                strScript.Clear();
            }
```